# PHP with Javascript: Email confirmation script not working

Tags: php, javascript

echo "
        function finishForm() {
         var answer = confirm('Are you sure these are the teams you want to enter with?');
         if (answer) {
          if(document.getElementByID(emailconfirm).value == ".$_SESSION[Email].") {
           form.action=\"esubmit.php\";
           form.submit();
          } else {
           alert('E-mail address do not match');
           return false;
          }
         } 
        }
        function restartForm() {
         var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to start over?');
         if (answer) {
          form.action=\"e1.php\";
          form.submit();
         }
        }
         ";

I have a regular button calling this function. emailconfirm is a text input.
I want to confirm that they have chosen the right teams, then check if the email in the session and the email confirmation text match. If they do match Then i want to submit the form.
If they dont match, I want to alert the user they dont match, and just return to page so user can check emails and then resubmit.
This script is in my header.

EDIT: Haha sorry i submitted one before and it didnt go through, forgot to add my problem!!

When you click the button it comes up with the confirmation, clicking either yes or no doesnt do anything. The alert doesnt pop up if they dont match and if they do match it doesnt submit. Also it might be good to note I had it without the email confirmation if statement and it worked fine (going to the submit page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is Case Sensitive, GetElementByID != GetElementById and thus should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to submit the form to php, check if the email is in the session and return to the form if it isn't.

The problem with the way you are doing it now is this: look at the source of the html page and you'll see the required email in the javascript. Now all I have to do is copy + paste that into the emailconfirm field and I'm in.

Comment: I dont really mind if they want to go into the source and copy paste the email...My concern atm is that the alerts arent popping up and if they email is the same nothing is happening

Comment: As Dormilich says, Javascript is case sensitive so you need to change getElementByID to getElementById

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `form` variable anywhere; saying `form.submit()` isn't going to get very far. Assuming form name of "frm" or something, put something in the likes of

```
var form = document.getElementById("frm");
```

earlier in your code.

Comment: additionally, regarding "document.getElementByID(emailconfirm)", the method is called getElementById() (JavaScript is case-sensitive) and emailconfirm is an undefined variable.

Comment: Good eye for noticing that! I've done that myself a number of times, and apparently I still don't spot that mistake.